# Связь моделей в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Вообщем, есть задача связать две модели связью много-ко-много. Есть модель Project и есть модель People. В проектах есть поле leader, которое я хочу реализовать так, чтобы при добавление проекта в админке, в поле лидер был выпадающий список, откуда можно было бы выбрать из всего списка людей. Я сделал следующий код, но он выдает ошибку, помогите разобраться:

```
class People(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    email = models.EmailField()



    def __str__(self):
        return self.lastName + ' ' + self.firstName


class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    text = models.TextField()
    small_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='style/static/img')
    big_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='style/static/img')
    description = models.TextField()
    users = models.ManyToManyField(People)
    leader = models.CharField(max_length= 100, choices= 
    People.objects.all())



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Вариант с KeyForeign

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    text = models.TextField()
    small_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='style/static/img')
    big_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='style/static/img')
    description = models.TextField()
    users = models.ForeignKey(People, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    list = People.objects.all()
    leader = models.CharField(max_length= 100, choices= list)
```

Comment: А почему не `leader = models.ForeignKey(People)`?

Comment: пробовал ForeignKey, тоже не работало. Да и в замысле, что помимо лидера будут члены проекта, то есть логически будет ко многим проектам много людей.

Comment: Многие-ко-многим у вас `users`.  Код с ForeignKey покажете?

Comment: добавил в сообщение темы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    text = models.TextField()
    small_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='style/static/img')
    big_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='style/static/img')
    description = models.TextField()
    users = models.ManyToManyField(People)
    leader = models.ForeignKey(People, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
```

без всяких `list` и `CharField` с `choices`.